# Calculate how each species is repeated in how many cells using QGIS

Tags: qgis, cell-statistics

I have created a grid map as a shapefile. I have added a point layer that includes “species name”, coordinates and etc. I put a part of it below.
[image: Figure 1: My Dataset]

This dataset including about 2400 species and 25000 points. I have create a grid map (712 cells 0.5 × 0.5), then I implemented these points on the map (Figure 2)

[image: Figure 2: The grid map and distribution points of species]

How I do calculate whether each species is repeated in how many cells?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to calculate. Do you want to find all squares where some (it doesnt matter which) species occur more than once?

Comment: I want to calculate Range-restricted endemic richness (RER). 
 RER was defined as the number of endemic species present in not more than five grid cells (ca. 1% of the study  area).
If you need, I can send you a part of the data set.

Comment: Do you know of some source I can read about Range-restricted endemic richness? I found very little on Google. It looks like you and me are working with the same kind of data / analysis. I'm analysing observations of Red Listed Species in Sweden

Comment: We used some floristics resources, especially flora Iranica (168 vols). In total, 2440 endemics species with 24,357 geo-referenced records were compiled as endemic to Iran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First dissolve by attribute "species name", then you have a multipoint geometry for every species. Open the field calculator in the dissolved layer and use this expression to calculate how many cells a species appears in.

```
array_length(
    overlay_within(
        'cells layer name/id', -- put the cells layer name inside quotes 
        1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL and create a virtual layer. If you have many points, this will take a while. I have 100k points and it took about 15 minutes to add the layer. (The same query in PostGIS take seconds, if you have access to it)

The first thing you should do after it has been added is to right click and export it to disk, for example as a geopackage, then delete the virtual layer.

Replace `scientificname` with the name of you species field, `observations` with the name of your point layer and `grid` with the name of your grid layer:

```sql
select name, count(gridid)
from (
select o.scientificname as name, g.id as gridid
from observations o
join grid g
on st_intersects(o.geometry, g.geometry)
group by name, gridid) sub
group by name
having count(gridid)<=5
order by name
```

[image]

Comment: I did as you said, but it gives this error: "Query prepation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column: g.id"

Comment: You are missing a column called id in your grid layer. Create it using Field Calculator: https://imgur.com/0LGzQsA.png

Comment: Thank you very much, I really had no idea what to do in such a short period of time!